# How to quote a shell variable in a TCL-expect string

Tags: awk, expect

I'm using the following awk command in an expect script to get the gateway for a particular destination

```
route | grep $dest | awk '{print $2}'
```

However the expect script does not like the $2 in the above statement.

Does anyone know of an alternative to awk to perform the same function as above? ie. output 2nd column.

Comment: you should never use variables like `$dest` in a shell without escaping them. Use `grep "$dest"` instead! Leaving them unquoted is only when you want whitespace in your variable to be interpreted as a real argument delimiter.

Comment: Does it work if you escape the dollar sign?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use cut:

```
route | grep $dest | cut -d \  -f 2
```

That uses spaces as the field delimiter and pulls out the second field

Comment: This will use spaces as delimiters, but if there are multiple spaces there will be one field for each space. It would be better to use sed before to remove duplicate spaces.

Comment: This has worked. Just for anybody interested the command `route | grep $dest` gave the output `10.21.1.1       10.12.1.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   2      0        0 ath1` (routing done via olsr in wireless mesh network for anyone interested). I have successfully used the following to extract the 2nd column from this, in an expect script. `route | grep 10.21.1.1 | sed -e 's/[ ]*/ /g' | cut -d \  -f 3`

Comment: Much leaner than `sed` is `tr`: `route | grep 10.21.1.1 | tr -s \  | cut -d \  -f 3`. But I've upvoted the answer that mentions `awk`, because that's really the best alternative here. :)

Answer (score 5):

To answer your Expect question, single quotes have no special meaning to the Tcl parser. You need to use braces to protect the body of the awk script:

```
route | grep $dest | awk {{print $2}}
```

And as awk can do what grep does, you can get away with one less process:

```
route | awk -v d=$dest {$0 ~ d {print $2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before switching to another utility, check if changing field separator worrks. Documentation for field separators in GNU Awk [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html#Field-Separators).

Answer (score 1):

SED is the best alternative to use. If you don't mind a dependency, Perl should also be sufficient to solve the task

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of your data, you can use either cut, or use sed to do both filtering and printing the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use Perl:

```
perl -ne 'if(/foo/) { @_ = split(/:/); print $_[1]; }'
```

This will print second token of each line containing `foo`, with `:` as token separator.